# I do not want to run socket.emit until I am ready to use it

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

So I don't want to fetch from the server socket.emit until I need it. Because everything is not prepared fully until then. How do I have socket.emit sit quietly until I am ready for it?

Server

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('adduser', function(player){
    ........
    }

    socket.emit('getQ', socket.Ques[0].question);

    ]
```

Client

```
    var retrieveQ = function (){
    socket.on('getQ', function(quesPick){
        quesObj = quesPick;
    })
```

The client is retrieveQ much later on its not suppose to be done at start, yet socket is emitting almost right away and giving me errors because socket.Ques is not made until later on.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, emit getQ  on response to a client request after  client socket  connects. Something like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('adduser', function(player){
    ........
    }
socket.on('askGetQ', function(zzz){
        socket.emit('getQ', socket.Ques[0].question);
    }    
}
```

On the client do:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('getQ', 'something');
});
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to emit from my client when I need it?

Comment: @BkRazor yes,thats my solution.Maybe there is a better one.

Comment: im going to mess around with your way for a little while and let you know if I can get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

node.js is an event driven environment.  So, sometime in the future there will be some sort of event on your server that will cause you to want to send this `.emit()`.  At that point, you need to be able to find the appropriate `socket` object and then use it to send the `.emit()`.

Since you haven't said exactly what event you want to use to send this emit, we can't really help more specifically.  If you care to explain that, we could probably offer specific code.

Answer (score 0):

On the client you should do:

```
  const chat = io.connect('http://localhost/chat')
  chat.on('connect', function () {
    chat.emit('getQ', socket.Ques[0].question);
  });
```